# Windows 10 Open Directory in Bash Ubuntu

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu

In Windows 10, is there a simple way to open a current directory (or file) into the Bash Ubuntu Shell?

Comment: type `bash` into the address bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open Command Prompt in current directory we type `cmd` in address bar for bash you should enter `bash` in address bar provided you have bash installed

Comment: This is helpful however, is there someway to make a shortcut that directly opens the bash window?

Comment: See this https://www.howtogeek.com/270810/how-to-quickly-launch-a-bash-shell-from-windows-10s-file-explorer/   It clearly details the simple process you should follow to get the shortcut.accept the answer if it helps!